# Download Excel File From Base64 text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I want to download excel file from base64 text in browser.

I can download pdf file without no problem like below

```
  function downloadPDF(attachment) {
        const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${attachment.base64Txt}`;
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        const fileName = `${attachment.name}.pdf`;

        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
    }
```

I tried same way for Excel like below. It downloads file but when I open in excel it says "The file and format extension don't match". I tried to rename file to xlsx and other excel types. But no luck

```
 function downloadExcel(attachment) {
            const linkSource = `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,${attachment.base64Txt}`;
            const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            const fileName = `${attachment.name}.xls`;
    
            downloadLink.href = linkSource;
            downloadLink.download = fileName;
            downloadLink.click();
        }
```

I am using latest React version.

Answer (score 0):

To download an Excel file from a base64 string in the browser, you can use the same approach as for downloading a PDF file. However, you need to use the correct MIME type for Excel files, which is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet for .xlsx files and application/vnd.ms-excel for .xls files.

```
function downloadExcel(attachment) {
  const linkSource = `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,${attachment.base64Txt}`;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  const fileName = `${attachment.name}.xlsx`;

  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
}
```